# Initializing an array before initializing a pointer to that same array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to initialize an array and then initialize a pointer to that array.

```
int *pointer;
pointer = new int[4] = {3,4,2,6};
delete[] pointer;
pointer = new int[4] = {2,7,3,8};
delete[] pointer;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is doing this on the heap a requirement?  You didn't mention in your question.

Comment: Well, I just want a way that I can update the same pointer to new arrays, but the arrays need to be initialized. So I think it has to be done on the heap, but anyway that works will make me happy.

Comment: What's the bigger picture here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use

```
int array[4] = {3, 4, 2, 6};
```

Is there a reason you want to allocate memory for the array from heap?

Suggestion after comment:

```
int arrays[32][4] = {{3, 4, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, ...}
int *pointers[4];
pointers[0] = arrays[0];
pointers[1] = arrays[12];
pointers[2] = arrays[25];
pointers[3] = arrays[13];
...
pointers[0] = arrays[13];
pointers[1] = arrays[11];
pointers[2] = arrays[21];
pointers[3] = arrays[6];
```

Comment: Well I'm writing a function that will have 32 arrays in it, basically the same 4 arrays but with different members. I wanted to somehow keep it to 4 arrays and re-initialize them at 8 different points in the function.

Comment: You could just re-use those four arrays by overwriting them with the new numbers needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "overwriting them"?

Comment: The suggestion after comment would work, but won't that use a lot of memory the entire duration of the function? I was hoping to spread it out so the memory foot print would be lower. It's the best solution so far though.

Comment: Yes it uses more memory, but I wouldn't say that it uses a lot of memory :) What kind of environment do you have?

Comment: Its not an environment restriction, I am just attempting to write the best code I can. I still have much to learn.

Comment: Well in almost any situation, reserving 32 * 4 * 4 bytes from stack is totally acceptable.

Comment: @Alex: I'd say, first try to write correct, easily readable code. Then optimize.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *pointer = new int[4]{3,4,2,6};
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, this is C++0x syntax.  To do this in earlier versions, write a function that takes a stack array + size, allocates a new array on the heap, loops through the stack array populating the heap array, and then returning a pointer to the heap array.

```
int* foo( const int size, int *array )
{
   int *newArray = new int[size];
   for( int index = 0; index < size; ++index )
   {
      newArray[index] = array[index];
   }

   return newArray;
}
```

The call would look like this:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *ptr = foo( 4, a );
```

It takes two lines, but it at least is easier than initializing line by line.

Answer (score 0):

```
//initialize the array
int array[] = {3,4,2,6};
// initialize a pointer to that array
int *pointer = array;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that *pointer can ONLY be used in this scope because it points to a stack variable that will be removed from the stack once scope exits.

Comment: Making sure your pointer points to valid data before using using it is kind of obvious, isn't it?
One can definitely have pointer point to any of 'the same 4 arrays but with different members' (as Alex needs).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can initialize non heap arrays, e.g.:

```
 static const int ar1[4] = { ... };
 static const int ar2[4] = { ... };
```

Then initialize your dynamically allocated array from the static data:

```
void func()
{
    int *pointer = new int[4];
    ...
    memcpy(pointer, ar1, sizeof(ar1));
    ...
    memcpy(pointer, ar2, sizeof(ar2));
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with a standard container and boost::assign.

```
std::vector vect = list_of(3)(4)(2)(6);

...

vect = list_of(2)(7)(3)(8);
```